# pagekit - query search issue

Tags: php, symfony, pagekit

I create an extension called `material` and everything works fine. I want to implement simple search query, so I sampled it from `bixie/portfolio` extension which you can get it from `marketplace`. So I have this code in my `MaterialController`:

```
$user_id = App::user()->id;
        $query  = array_values(Material::query()->where('user_id = ?', [$user_id])->get());
        $filter = array_merge(array_fill_keys(['search', 'order', 'limit'], ''), $filter);

        extract($filter, EXTR_SKIP);

        if ($search) {
            $query->where(function ($query) use ($search) {  //<-- this throw error.
                $query->orWhere(['name LIKE :search'], ['search' => "%{$search}%"]);
            });
        }
```

and I will get fatal error:

> Fatal error:  Call to a member function where() on array in line...

What do the error mean?

I googled a bit and some comment that  function where() need to use with collections. How can I resolve it in this case?

I am using `pagekit 1.0.12`, `symfony ~3.0.0`.

Comment: `$query` is __array__. Why you do `array_values` - I dunno.

Comment: I am new in `symfony` so not sure what's the different. I used it in my other function and it works, so I thought I can just use that. what else would you suggest then if that is not appropriate ?

Comment: Remove `array_values`?

Answer (score 0):

A proper version of  code is:

```
$user_id = App::user()->id;
// init query and add filter by `user_id`
// DO NOT use `get` and `array_values`, because 
// these functions __change__ type of `$query`
$query  = Material::query()->where('user_id = ?', [$user_id]);

$filter = array_merge(array_fill_keys(['search', 'order', 'limit'], ''), $filter);
extract($filter, EXTR_SKIP);

if ($search) {
    // add additional filtering
    $query->where(function ($query) use ($search) {
        $query->orWhere(['name LIKE :search'], ['search' => "%{$search}%"]);
    });
}

// get/return results of a query
return $query->get();
```

Comment: I tried your code and got `500 - internal server error`. but when I tried `$query  = Material::query()`, then I get the result. any idea?

Comment: With filter by `$search` I suppose you need to use `andWhere`

Comment: after many unsuccessful attempts, I go back to old school way: `$query->where('user_id ='.$user_id.' AND name LIKE "'.$search.'%"');`